# How to execute many functions one after the other

Tags: python

I'd like to execute many function after the other. Each function returns True or False. So if one function returns True, I'd like to execute the next one. etc...

All the functions don't have necessary the same arguments.

Now i have something like :

```
res=function1()
if res:
   res=function2()
   if res:
      res=function2()
```

And it goes on and on for like 20 functions. Is there a better way to do this ?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you can define your own way to do this, but I would do that like that:

```
my_functions = (
    (my_func1, [2, 5], {'kwarg1': 'val1'}),
    # ...
)

for function, args, kwargs in my_functions:
    if not function(*args, **kwargs):
        break
```

Edited according to the comment. Great insight!

Comment: If tuples are used instead of a dictionary it could also be written as:
    `for f, args, kwargs in my_functions:
        if not f(*args,**kwargs):
            break`

same effect though

Comment: @abarnert Original version was a list, but now I've changed it to tuple.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably use [`partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to make zero-argument functions that you can loop over (instead of some kind of structure with the function and its arguments):

```
functions = [
    functools.partial(func1, arg1a, arg1b),
    functools.partial(func2),
    functools.partial(func3, keyword_a=kwarg3a, keyword_b=kwarg3b)
]
```

Then, instead of putting it into a `list` and iterating over it, you can just call [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
retval = all(func() for func in (
    functools.partial(func1, arg1a, arg1b),
    functools.partial(func2),
    functools.partial(func3, keyword_a=kwarg3a, keyword_b=kwarg3b)
))
```

That will return `False` as soon as one of the functions returns `False` (or anything false-y), or run all of the functions and return `True` if they all return `True` (or anything true-y). As the docs say, it's equivalent to:

```
def all(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if not element:
            return False
    return True
```

It's worth comparing the `partial`s to the `tuple`s in the other answer, which serve as pseudo-partials, both in how they're defined and in how they're called:

```
f1 = functools.partial(func, arg1, arg2, kw1=kwarg1, kw2=kwarg2)
f2 = (func1, (arg1a, arg1b), {'kw1': kwarg1, 'kw2': kwarg2 })

f1()
f2[0](*f2[1], **f2[2])
```

Obviously you can (and should, as aemdy's answer does) make the call more readable with tuple-unpacking, but it's still never going to be as simple as using a real partial.

Comment: The Python community tends to be afraid of `functools`, but for my money, this is the most readable.

Comment: @Cairnarvon: Maybe the Python 2.x community or the people who learned from 10-year-old books are afraid of `functools`, but actual Python developers use `partial` all over the place. For example, Guido's examples for `tulip` are full of it. And using it in place of `lambda` functions or pseudo-partials stored in `tuple`s is exactly what it's there for.

Comment: +1 for the comparison to the tuple approach. If people are still afraid of `functools`, this example makes it obvious that they should not be.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the short-circuiting behaviour of the `and` operator:

```
function1() and function2() and function3() and ...
```

`function2` will only be called if `function1` returned `True`, `function3` will only be called if `function1` and `function2` returned `True`, and so on.

It's not necessarily very Pythonic, though.

Since you're always assigning to `res`, you can also just keep the `if`s flat:

```
res = function1()

if res:
    res = function2()

if res:
    res = function3()
```

That could considered more readable, but it does waste a lot of vertical space. At least you aren't nesting `if`s two dozen deep, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to get too complicated:

```
res = function1()
res = res and function2()
res = res and function3()
...
```

This looks a little odd, but will do what you want, without having to twist around the function calls themselves into lists of dictionaries or something. It's just a longer way of writing Cairnarvon's answer:

```
res = (
   function1() and
   function2() and
   function3() and
   ...
   )
```